# Angular expression in text input "value"

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that user will have to fill in. Some fields are dates and i don't want user to have to type in today's date.

**My Form**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="JobOrderController as jOrder"> 
    <form class="form-inline" ng-submit>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="todaysDate"><h4><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag'></span> Date</h4>Date </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todaysDate" ng-model="jOrder.orderData.date" value="{{ 2 + 4 }}" >
        </div>
    ......... more code .........
```

**My Controller**

```
angular.module('jobOrderCtrl', ['jobOrderService'])

.controller('JobOrderController', function(Jobs, socketio) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.createOrders = function() {
        vm.message = '';
        Jobs.createOrders(vm.orderData)
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.orderData = '';
                vm.message = data.message;
            });
    };
});
```

I try out using js to write to that date input field, but is not showing due to angular data binding.

So what i want is the date input value field to be today's date. So how do i go about and do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you set the date?

`orderData` should be an object with the form fields - NOT a string

initialize the orderData:

```
var vm = this;
vm.orderData = { date : new Date()};
```

and remove the `value` property form the html input field. Also set type to `date`

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="todaysDate" ng-model="jOrder.orderData.date" >
```

Comment: Thanks... i was trying vm.orderData.date = new Date();

Comment: That would work as well - if vm.orderData was already initialized. if vm.orderData is null you will get and `undefined` error